# JS: Find URLs in Text, Make Links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What would be the following PHP code rewritten in JS be, so that url links inside of text blobs could be replaced with html links? I've started a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rZrp/).

```
<?php

// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com";

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

   // make the urls hyper links
   echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);

} else {

   // if no urls in the text just return the text
   echo $text;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
var text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com";
text = text.replace(
    /((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?)/g,
    '<a href="$1">$1</a>'
);
```

Explanation:

The `g` here is a global flag; it will replace all urls.

I also added an capture group for the entire expression, so I could use the backreference `$1`.

Comment: This does not ignore already hyperlinked urls.