# Vuejs link url in content

Tags: vue.js

How can I make clickable link of url's in my content?

Imagine you have piece of code `{{post.caption}}` and it returns one paragraph, something like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam sunt
> nostrum nihil, illum nam ipsam at, ratione, https://google.com officia
> aperiam excepturi odio adipisci cum quo minus quibusdam laborum
> debitis voluptatibus temporibus.

I want `https://google.com` to be linked automatically.

**any suggestion?**

**Update**

I've just noticed that caption data for line brakes uses `\n\n` and `\n` and it's attached to the url's in texts so basically is some like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam sunt\n\nnostrum nihil, illum nam ipsam at, ratione,\n\nhttps://google.com officia\n\naperiam excepturi odio adipisci cum quo minus quibusdam laborum debitis voluptatibus temporibus.

could it be the reason why answers below didn't work?

Comment: Perhaps something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19625209/8126784

Comment: @Lk77 no, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `v-html` after format the paragraph first?

Comment: nope! it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

My solution bases on 3 step:

- Step 1: Detect the href link in the variable.
- Step 2: Change string link to a href tag by regex function.
- Step 3: Use v-html to show it in browser.

You can test it by my vue simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vuejs 3</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <p v-html="formatHrefLink(post.caption)"></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    const { createApp } = Vue
    createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          message: 'Hello Vue!'
        }
      },
      setup() {
        var post = {};
        return {
          post
        };
      },
      created() {
        this.post.caption = `Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam sunt nostrum nihil, illum nam ipsam at, ratione, https://google.com officia aperiam excepturi odio adipisci cum quo minus quibusdam laborum debitis voluptatibus temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam sunt nostrum nihil, illum nam ipsam at, ratione, https://google.com officia aperiam excepturi odio adipisci cum quo minus quibusdam laborum debitis voluptatibus temporibus.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam sunt nostrum nihil, illum nam ipsam at, ratione, http://127.0.0.1:8080?test1=1&test2=abc#paragraph1 officia aperiam excepturi odio adipisci cum quo minus quibusdam laborum debitis voluptatibus temporibus.`;
      },
      methods: {
        formatHrefLink(string) {
          const regex = /(https?:\/\/[\w\.\d:?&=#]+)/gm;
          const subst = `<a href="$1">$1</a>`;
          const result = string.replace(regex, subst);
          return result;
        }
      }
      
    }).mount('#app')
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

One problem is one party, do you agree with me : D

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: I checked my example, it runs well, check again your `post.caption` and define the regex variable to suit with.

Comment: Could you give me your `post.caption` value for my testing?

Comment: here is sample for you:  ```"caption": "Project management web application. \n\nFeature:\n\nMulti level access\nProject progress report\nProject timeline\nTeam members\nTasks\nCalendars\nKanbans\nMeetings\nDocuments\nTemplates\nExports\nClients\n\nCustom build functionalities based on requests:\n\n⚫HR management\n⚫Sales management\n\nDemo:\nhttp://google.com\n\n#project #management #web #app #sell #buy #webapplication #project_manager #company",```

Comment: it says `string is undefined`

Comment: This case it still runs well at: https://regex101.com/r/HFhYIq/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250134/discussion-between-protoproto-and-mafortis).

Comment: Hey man, I've managed to get your code to work by adding if statement around it `if(string != undefined) {//code...}` but it has 1 issue, it stops on domain `.com` and anything after `.com` will not be include link. (e.g. https://google.com/123) it only links `https://google.com`

Comment: Change the regex to: `const regex = /(https?:\/\/[\/\w\.\d:?&=#]+)/gm;`. See this: https://regex101.com/r/U9kgd2/1